# Association, Aggregation, Composition in GORM

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

Say, if two classes A,B are in relation like A *hasMany* B. In GORM  how to specify these relationships between domain classes

1. Association
2. Aggregation
3. Composition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you wanted to know which one the above options is signified by a `hasMany` relationship?

The answer is "Association". You can go through [GORM reference document](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html) for details about Association and Composition.

Comment: yes, thats partially correct. But from a design point of view how to maintain the aggregation and composition.

Comment: @user2463026 You can obtain the same using `embedded` in domain class. Again, do visit the docs for details about embedded. Look for 'Composition in GORM'.

Comment: @user2463026 Did you get what you were looking for?

Comment: @user2463026 Glad it did. Will the answer be appropriate for acceptance now?